# Default constructor and open generics in MEF 2 using conventions

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, mef

I am trying to use MEF 2 in my project, I usually use SimpleInjector but this time I wanted to try MEF. My main problem is dealing with open generics, this is what i got so far

```
public interface ISetting {}
public class Setting : ISetting {}

public interface ILogger<TLog>
{
    TLog Fetch()
}

public class Logger<TLog> : ILogger<TLog>
{
    private ISetting settings;

    public Logger(ISetting settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    public TLog Fetch()
    {
        return default(TLog);
    }
}
```

Now for the container part I do

```
var conventions = new ConventionBuilder();

conventions.ForType<Setting>()
           .Export<ISetting>()
           .Shared();

conventions.ForType(typeof(Logger<>))
           .Export(t => t.AsContractType(typeof(ILogger<>)))
           .Shared();

var configuration = new ContainerConfiguration()
        .WithAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly,conventions);

using (var container = configuration.CreateContainer)
{
    var export = container.GetExport<ILogger<object>>(); //Exception :(
}
```

When it's trying to retrieve the export I am getting this exception

> No importing constructor was found on type 'MEFTest.Logger`1[System.Object]'.

If I remove the constructor from the Logger class the container construct the closed generic just fine. I am 98% sure that the problem is related with the constructors but I feel I am missing something here

**Edit 1:** Doing some reading I have actually discovered that there are 2 versions of MEF, one that is a Nuget package and another one that ships with .NET40, the one that I am using is the Nuget package. I did some refactoring to use the one that ships with .NET40

All the code is the same except for the part that creates and use the container

```
var category = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), conventions);

using (var container = new CompositionContainer(category))
{
    var logic = container.GetExport<ILogger<int>>().Value; //Lazy Initialization O.o
    var test = logic.Fetch();

    // the rest of the code …
}
```

This works :) just fine so definitely I am missing something in the version of the Nuget package

**Edit 2:** With the removal of the *"auto-detection"* of the generic parts in the *WithAssembly* method the code works, here is the code refactored

The convention part:

```
var conventions = new ConventionBuilder();

conventions.ForType<Setting>()
           .Export<ISetting>();

conventions.ForType<Logger<int>>()
           .Export<ILogger<int>>();
```

The container part:

```
var types = new Type[] { typeof(Setting), typeof(Logger<int>) };

var configuration = new ContainerConfiguration()
        .WithParts(types, conventions);

using (var container = configuration.CreateContainer())
{
    var logic = container.GetExport<ILogger<int>>();
    var test = logic.Fetch();

    // the rest of the code …
}
```

I changed the specific type to **integer**.When it executes *Fetch()* it returns correctly 0 as the default value for int

The interesting part is why the *"auto-detection"* of the generics force the constructor to be marked

**Edit 3:** I think the *"auto-detection"* part is not the one at fault here because I have tried this

```
var conventions = new ConventionBuilder();

conventions.ForType<Setting>()
           .Export<ISetting>();

conventions.ForType(typeof(Logger<>))
           .Export(t => t.AsContractType(typeof(ILogger<>)));

var types = new Type[] { typeof(Setting), typeof(Logger<>) };

var configuration = new ContainerConfiguration()
        .WithParts(types, conventions);

using (var container = configuration.CreateContainer())
{
    var logic = container.GetExport<ILogger<int>>();
    var test = logic.Fetch();

    // the rest of the code …
}
```

With that code I am back to square one because it produces the same exception, it enforces the use of the marking attribute

**Edit 4:** The actual MEF project has gone to the *CoreFx GitHub* page under *System.Composition*. I went to the unit tests and in the *RegistrationBuilderCompatibilityTest* lines 40-58

```
public interface IRepository<T> { }

public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> { }

[Fact]
public void ConventionBuilderExportsOpenGenerics()
{
    var rb = new ConventionBuilder();

    rb.ForTypesDerivedFrom(typeof(IRepository<>))
      .Export(eb => eb.AsContractType(typeof(IRepository<>)));

    var c = new ContainerConfiguration()
        .WithPart(typeof(EFRepository<>), rb)
        .CreateContainer();

    var r = c.GetExport<IRepository<string>>();
}
```

They never tested it without the default constructor

**Results:** I end up opening an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10627) on the CoreFx Github page and submitted a [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/10665) with a fix for the bug

Comment: I already tried `SelectConstructor(ctr => ctr.FirstOrDefault())` and is a no go. **BTW** if I remove the generics from all this it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until they merge my [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/10665) and release a version with the bug fixed I recommend going with the solution on **Edit 2**. I think it is the least intrusive way of achieving the functionality required

Basically you need to build conventions with your **CLOSED** generic types and create a collection with these closed generics. In the container use the **WithParts** method along with the **conventions** that were defined, see **Edit 2** for code snippet

**UPDATE**

My [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/15315) has been merged and this functionality is now supported. It will be released in **corefx 2.0** due by April 30, 2017

Answer (score 1):

Try marking the constructor with the [ImportingConstructor] attribute.

```
using System.Composition;
...
[ImportingConstructor]
public Logger(ISetting settings)
{
    this.settings = settings;
}
```

Comment: I would like to avoid the use of markups because if I put this code into a library I am assuming  that the client is gonna use MEF to inject the classes. Also, something is off even with the markup cuz if I remove the constructor MEF is gonna use the default one even without marking. I dont know if I am explain it clear enough

Comment: Your solution works, according to this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee155691(v=vs.110).aspx in the **Prerequisite Imports** it says that MEF will select the default constructor and throw an error if no [ImportingConstructor] is defined or there are multiple [ImportingConstructor] defined, but as I said this should be possible without markups using conventions